# Expo "Cannot find module 'color-convert'" Problem :(

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I have problem! I just write terminal `npm start` and it shows:

```
Starting project at /home/pc/Documents/Projects/Mobile/weather_app
Developer tools running on http://localhost:19002
Cannot find module 'color-convert'
Require stack:
- /home/pc/Documents/Projects/Mobile/weather_app/node_modules/ansi-styles/index.js
- /home/pc/Documents/Projects/Mobile/weather_app/node_modules/chalk/index.js
- /home/pc/Documents/Projects/Mobile/weather_app/node_modules/@babel/code-frame/node_modules/@babel/highlight/lib/index.js
- /home/pc/Documents/Projects/Mobile/weather_app/node_modules/@babel/code-frame/lib/index.js
- /home/pc/Documents/Projects/Mobile/weather_app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js
- /home/pc/Documents/Projects/Mobile/weather_app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js
- /home/pc/Documents/Projects/Mobile/weather_app/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js
- /home/pc/Documents/Projects/Mobile/weather_app/node_modules/metro/src/IncrementalBundler.js
- /home/pc/Documents/Projects/Mobile/weather_app/node_modules/metro/src/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/build/metro/importMetroFromProject.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/build/HermesBundler.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/build/MetroDevServer.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/build/start/startDevServerAsync.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/build/internal.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/build/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/build/exp.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
```

Please, help me fixing the problem!

> npm version: 8.3.1

> node version: v17.3.0

> expo version: 5.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite sure what might have caused your problem but you can try the following fixes and see if any of them works for you:

1. `$ npm i color-convert` to make sure you have installed the module color-convert.
2. `$ expo r -c` to clear cache and restart your app, it could be that your app has not updated that cache after installing the module color-convert.
3. You may also delete `node-modules` directory and run again `npm i` or `yarn`  to download and all the modules and their correct dependencies.